# Wordpress & Ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm creating a plugin and I want to implement drag & drop capabilities that save the order of li's in a list and then displays that list on the front end of the website. I may be a little over my head as I don't know a lot about ajax. Are there any barebones and simple tutorials out there that explain something similar to this?

Comment: Have you searched the [tag:ajax] archive? Asking for tutorials is out of scope for this site. Please try something, come back, show what you have tried and where you failed in an [edit].

Answer (score 1):

This link to the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) should help. It demonstrates a few different ways to POST using AJAX in a plugin. As for re-arranging your listed elements, this can be done a number of ways.

I would recommend running a search for rearranging elements using javascript. The jQuery function [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) can be used to drag/drop elements. For example, the following code can be used to move an element above the previous element:

```
$("p").click(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev()); 
});
```

or even something like this just to manually move a paragraph above the other:

```
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>
<!--javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#2').insertBefore('#1');
</script>
```

It's hard to help out much more without any further information.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was hoping to use jQuery UI.

Here is a good example of what I'm trying to do. https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ -> Basically it's a social network plugin so in the admin section you'd drag and drop the order of your social networks. 
<li><a class="author-fb" href="www.facebook.com/">facebook</a></li> is an example

Comment: So far everything is working well I guess the issue I'm having is hooking it into WP database and calling it up again. I'm guessing POST would be the best way but I'm very much a beginner when it comes to ajax.

Comment: Here's a tip. Call a function every time a user drops an element into place. Inside of this function POST your information to the database using AJAX.

Just take a look at the Codex page I linked you, it gives about all the information you should need to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out! I really appreciate your help!